# Laravel 9 Redirect user to specific view folder after login

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 9. I have 2 controllers, 1 for admin and 1 for manager. I have my views separated and in their respective folder.

I added a column to the users table called 'is_admin'. If it's an manager, I want them to be directed to the manager views and deny access to others.

My admin route group starts with this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'middleware' => 'is_admin'], function () {
admin routes....
```

Can someone guide me on the manager one? I want them redirected to manager.index and restrict the other routes views.

I have searched this issue but can only find results for laravel 5.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there can be a lot of ways to do this job.

one way is to use one middleware and check the user role i.e is_admin or manager and redirect it to specific paths.

now that you are using 2 middlewares in the is_admin middleware check if the role is admin then redirect to the admin views otherwise pass that request and similar for the other one as well.

create 2 middlewares
is_admin and is_manager
wrap your routes like
auth and is_admin
auth and is_manager
check for the role and redirect accordingly.